# Psfrag not replacing tags into LaTeX typeset

Tags: graphics, psfrag

I am trying to use the psfrags package to include LaTeX typeset into my .eps figures, but it is not working.

I have followed the instructions provided in the following [link](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/psfrag/). The psfrag.sty file is correctly installed in the correct place (I also have it in the current working directory) and is loaded without any warnings or errors. I also have the psfrag.pro file in the same working directory so this shouldn't be an issue (but I am unsure as to how to put it in the directory where the PostScript driver looks for header files).

**Here is a MWE:**

I have loaded the psfrag.sty and am trying to include an image:

```
\usepackage{psfrag} 

\begin{figure}[htb]
\begin{center}
\begin{psfrags}
\psfrag{y}{$\rho_y$}
\includegraphics[width =\textwidth]{stationary_spe_chain_copy.eps}
\end{psfrags}
\caption{Some caption}
\label{pic:stationary_spe_chain}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
```

The image has a simple textbox letter reading y, which I want LaTeX to replace with $\rho_y$. The image generated has the original letter y.

I have made sure that the graphics path is correct - this is not an issue. Are there any suggestions as to what I could try?

I am using TexShop on a Mac.

Comment: (1) the center env should not be used to center inside floats. (2) how exactly are you compiling this in texshop? Have you asked it to run latex + dvips?

Comment: @daleif, in the dropdown list TexShop, I have chosen LaTeX and then I just press Typeset. How do I make it run LaTeX + dvips? Thanks!

Comment: Isn't there a dvips item as well? Otherwise use the terminal to do it manually

Comment: @daleif No there isn't a dvips item. How would I do it from the terminal?

Comment: Run latex from Texshop, run dvips file.dvi in terminal plus ps2pdf file.ps to get a PDF you can view. You might want to Google to see if there isn't a better method when using texshop